# Visual C# - Capturar evento clic de un botón

Tags: c#

Quisiera saber cómo crear una función que capture si el botón "sumarBtn" es presionado.

```
Public void operar(float a, float b) {
    if (sumarBtn is Pressed) {
        //Hello!! 
    } else if (restarBtn is Pressed) {
        //hello
    } else if (multiplicarBtn is Pressed) {
        //hello
    } else if (dividirBtn is Pressed) {
        //hello
    } else {
        //ningún botón presionado, error
    } 
}
```

Comment: @MiquelColl la pregunta trata de evaluar si un botón está o ha sido presionado por el usuario. El IDE es irrelevante.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Creo que sería buena idea mantenerlo en el sentido de que 1. Esta respuesta es muy ámplia y si se acota a un IDE las posibles respuestas se reducen y se puede ser más preciso. 2- La respuesta que ya existe y en la que el usuario ha comentado da a entender que puede ser una buena respuesta. Si se quita esa etiqueta la pregunta carece de sentido tal y cómo está formulada... Al menos yo no sé cómo contestarla (y puede ser ese el problema, mi limitación). Un saludo.

Comment: @MiquelColl no es amplia. Es algo sencillo, es un delegate y debes asignar el delegate de alguna manera. Cómo puedes hacerlo, ya viene una serie de explicaciones. Nuevamente, **el IDE es innecesario**, puedes hacer esto en Mono y en un bloc de notas, el compilado y su funcionamiento será similar. Te recomiendo también leer [este comentario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/15787/visual-c-capturar-evento-clic-de-un-bot%c3%b3n#comment26231_15795).

Comment: Pero Luiggi, hombre. Cuando yo trabajo con un IDE, siempre asigno dicho IDE a las etiquetas, para que le sea más fácil al personaje que responde saber dar la respuesta dependiendo de lo que yo esté necesitando.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz el IDE es irrelevante. Imagina esto, ¿qué pasa si un programador utiliza otro IDE como [rider](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/) para trabajar en C#? ¿Acaso esta respuesta no aplica para él también solo porque usa un IDE distinto? Solo se debe utilizar las etiquetas de IDE **cuando** la pregunta está directamente asociada al IDE. Por ejemplo: "¿Cómo filtrar archivos en el explorer interno del IDE?", "¿Por qué el IDE se cuelga con la instrucción XYZ?", "¿Me aparece el error ASDFGH cuando utilizo el plugin JKL en el IDE TYU, cómo resolverlo?" y así.

Comment: Vale, hombre. Disculpa, soy nuevo en Visual Studio con C# y en Stack Overflow, pues ya he hecho algunas preguntas pero no me he sabido dar a entender bien. Gracias por todo amigos, y por aclarar los puntos. Almenos tú Luiggi me hablaste antes de darme un punto negativo o flaggear mi pregunta. No como otros... Que podría mencionar en otras discusiones.

Comment: Saludos, tenía esta misma duda y reconozco que es muy buena la idea que se plantea en la respuesta, pero sigo con la duda ya que es genial tener el control sobre los botones, en este caso, que han sido pulsados pero es la propia acción de invocar el evento quién debería llamar al controlador C# y no revisar luego como se propone, para ver si algunos de dichos botones han sido accionados. Desearía, y es mi pregunta, saber si es posible y como hacer para asociar un controlador de eventos en C# a los eventos desencadenados en un documento web (html con cc, javascript, etc.) hosteado en un webBrow

Comment: Hola @RoilerJ.GonzálezRojas J., te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow en español. Si tienes una nueva pregunta, debes [crear tu propia publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Te recomiendo que antes leas [ask] y que completes el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio en general. Un saludo.

Comment: @RoilerJ.GonzálezRojas es una muy interesante pregunta amigo. Tienes la oportunidad de preguntar y como eres nuevo en la comunidad te ayudarán a que la pregunta sea mejor en caso de tener algunas falencias. Sólo que claro, así como hay bueno, también hay personajes que no toleran nada, cuídate de ellos. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si entiendo bien tu pregunta, quieres saber si el `button` sumarbtn ha sido presionado en algún momento.

Una manera de solucionarlo es utilizar el `click` del propio botón para guardar en una variable propia que éste ha sido presionado y así con posterioridad poder consultar si éste ha sido pulsado. Cómo lo haría:

```
private bool sumarBtnFuePresionado = false;

private void sumarBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sumarBtnFuePresionado = true;
}

Public void operar(float a, float b) {
    if (sumarBtnFuePresionado ) {
        //Hello!! 
    } 
}
```

La única manera que hay de saber si un botón se ha presionado es con el propio método `click` por eso es necesario utilizar el evento `OnClick()` para guardarte esta información.

Si tienes varios botones tienes que replicar esta lógica en cada uno de ellos. Dado tu ejemplo:

```
private bool sumarBtnFuePresionado = false;
private bool restarBtnFuePresionado = false;
private bool multiplicarBtnFuePresionado = false;
private bool dividirBtnFuePresionado = false;

private void sumarBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    sumarBtnFuePresionado = true;
}

private void restarBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    restarBtnFuePresionado = true;
}

private void multiplicarBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    multiplicarBtnFuePresionado = true;
}

private void dividirBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    dividirBtnFuePresionado = true;
}

Public void operar(float a, float b) {
    if (sumarBtnFuePresionado) {
        //Hello!! 
    } else if (restarBtnFuePresionado) {
        //hello
    } else if (multiplicarBtnFuePresionado) {
        //hello
    } else if (dividirBtnFuePresionado) {
        //hello
    } else {
        //ningún botón presionado, error
    } 

    //reiniciar los valores si esto es lo que quieres
    sumarBtnFuePresionado = false;
    restarBtnFuePresionado = false;
    multiplicarBtnFuePresionado = false;
    dividirBtnFuePresionado = false;

}
```

Cómo puedes ver al final puedes (o no) reiniciar los `bool` para que se haga un 'reset' y cuándo vuelvas a llamar esa función tenga en cuenta sólo los buttons presionados después de llamar esta función.

Todo este código es asumiendo que los botones que tengas definidos tengas en su `tag` la etiqueta `OnClick="nombreBoton_Click"`

Comment: Omg! Que ágil hombre. Usando bool, me gustó esta respuesta, pero antes la intentaré :)

Comment: Gracias por acomodarte a mi código.